# Using both Access Runtime 2013 and Access 2016 on one computer

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have here a specific application I am forced to use. This application uses Access as data storage.

This application is older and was once developed for Office 2013. Our company computers have now Office 2016 installed, with Access 2016.

After the installation of Access 2016 this application stopped running. It hangs immediately after start.

So i installed Access Runtime 2013 and application first worked fine. But as soon as I open Access 2016, there is a repair run installing something in the background and application again stopps working. After executing Repair on Access Runtime 2013, it works again until Access 2016 ist again opened.

After checking the dump of this Application I see that after running repair of Access 2013, Office15-DLLs are used. After starting Access 2016 and repair run, Office16-DLLs are linked and application stops working.

All those repair runs take minutes, so they are very annoying, as I often have to switch between both applications.

Is there any other / better way to handle it? I tried to set Runtime 2013 into the PATH of my application, no changes. Can I somehow force the application to use Runtime 2013 instead of Access 2016?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is possible. :( If I'm wrong, I'd love to hear about it, we have a similar situation with a program that requires Access 2013 and conflicts with Office 365. We use virtual machines for the Access 2013 app. :(

Comment: It sounds like you have the MSI version of Office 2016 installed (Volume License). Is it possible to switch to a Click-to-Run version instead (e.g. the retail versions of Office 2016/2019/2022 or the Microsoft 365 subscription versions)? We develop Access-based applications, so I have a lot of different Access versions installed simultaneously on my machine, and, in my experience, this "repair" issue only occurs between MSI versions.

Comment: That having been said, the "correct" solution would be to fix your application so that it works correctly with Office 2016. Note that Office 2013 [goes out of support in less than a year](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-office-2013).

Comment: Fixing for 2016 is unfortunately out of scope, as this is foreign application we bought once. There is no new version and probably will never be, so yes, we consider switching to another provider here, but this is a task for > 1 year of work, so nothing that can be done easily.

Comment: Yes, we have a MSI version installed (large company with many hundreds computer). Are you sure about that problem existing with MSI only? I can check within the software department, if there is a possibilitty of switching to Click-to.Run

Comment: @DigitalMachine: Well, I can confirm that the "repair run" thing does not happen with Click-to-Run on the machines I tested. Whether it will solve the problem with your app or not, I cannot say. I suggest that you test it on a virtual machine. (On the other hand, if you will plan to the software for longer than the Office 2013 EOL date, moving the whole application to a secured VM without Office 2016 would be an even better option. You don't want to surf the web on a machine that has an unsupported version of Office installed.)